# Sumar Totales Facturas Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

necesito ayuda para sumar el dato general de ventas por empleado ya que tengo una consuta que trae todo el detalle de la venta pero estoy teniendo problemas al intentar sumar el total de la venta por empleado ya que por cada linea lo suma aunque sea el mismo numero de factura [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.DocEntry,T2.[firstName]+' '+ T2.[lastName] as Empleado,T0.[DocNum] as Factura,(CASE WHEN T0.DocSubType='--' Then 'Factura' else 'Nota de Debito' end) as Tipo_Documento,'OINV' AS TABLA, T0.[DocDate] as Fecha,T1.[ItemCode] as Codigo,T1.[Dscription] as Descripcion,T0.CardName,
T1.[Quantity] as Cantidad, T1.[Price] as Precio,T1.[LineTotal] Total_Linea,T0.[DocTotal] as Total_Factura
from OINV T0,INV1 T1, OHEM T2
WHERE  T1.[DocEntry] =T0.[DocEntry]  and  T0.[DocDate] >=@fechainicio and  T0.[DocDate]<=@fechafin and T2.Code=t0.OwnerCode and T0.CANCELED='N'
group by T2.firstName,T2.lastName,t0.DocDate,T0.CardName,T1.ItemCode,T1.Dscription,t1.Quantity,T1.Price,T1.LineTotal,T0.DocTotal,t0.DocNum,t0.DocSubType,T0.DocEntry
order by t0.DocNum
```

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es la dificultad que se te presenta para sumar. Podrías [edit] la pregunta y explicarlo con otras palabras o, quizás, poner un ejemplo?